# Validating ADFS Configuration

Tags: azure, adfs

We have a client’s ADFS setup for a MVC App and we are setting it up using OWIN pipeline injection. We authenticate the user using app startup itself and no separate account controller logic exists.

```
//Setting up the Ws Federation

app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
                new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
                    {
                        Wtrealm = await configurationHandler.GetConfiguration(ConfigurationConstants.AdfsRelyingPartyIdentifier).ConfigureAwait(false),
                        MetadataAddress = await configurationHandler.GetConfiguration(ConfigurationConstants.AdfsFederationMetadataEndpoint).ConfigureAwait(false),
                        Notifications = new WsFederationAuthenticationNotifications
                                            {                                                AuthenticationFailed = context =>                                                    {
                                                        context.HandleResponse();
                                                        context.Response.Redirect("Logout/UnAuthorised");
                                                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                                                    }
                                            }
                    });

 //Inserting the authentication logic in OWIN pipeline

 app.Use( (context, continuation) =>  {  if (context.Authentication.User != null && context.Authentication.User.Identity != null && context.Authentication.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                        {
                            return continuation();
                        }

                        context.Authentication.Challenge(WsFederationAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    });
```

While creating a configuration validator, we have a requirement to validate the ADFS Relying Party Identifier and the federation metadata for different environments.
Our requirement is to validate that the two config values are correct and successfully redirect us to the client’s organizational login page.
We don’t intend to validate any user claims or successful login. If we get a successful login page, we are done.
Any ideas on how this can be done? All the resources available either validate the claims or setup WS federation as app startup.
Any help would be really appreciated.